# how to post multiple files to a url from jscript?

Tags: javascript, url, post, upload

I want to post multiple images to a url in order to upload them to the server. The challange is that it has to be done from only jscript.

Comment: You post multiple files the same way that you do a single file, just repeat them as different parameters. What problem are you having when you try it? Please post the code you attempted so we can help you fix it.

Comment: use jquery fileuploader plugin